# jQuery: get element inside object

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, json

So, I've got this code:

```
function popAreaTree() {

        var tree = $("ol.tree");
        var list1 = tree.children('li');
        var list2 = list1.children('ol').children('li');


        $(tree).on('click', $(this).children('li').children('a'), function(e, i) {
            console.log($(this).text());
            $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('open', 300);
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: '../admin/callbacks/jsonDataList.php',
            data: {t: 'zoneandarea'},
            dataType:"json",
            async: false,
            global: false,
            success: function(j, status) {
                for(var i = 0;1 < j.length; i++) {

                    var li = tree.append('<li class="zone"><a href="#">'+j[i].name+'</a></li>');
                    var areas = '';
                    $.each(j[i].areas, function(i, item) {
                        areas += '<li class="area" data-area-uid="'+item.uid+'">'+item.name+'</li>';
                    });
                    $(areas).insertAfter(li.closest('a')); // This is the problem
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

It is just basically creating a file tree. The ajax posts to a php page that outputs a json array with one more array inside each result. It goes like this:

```
array('name'=>name, 'uid'=>uid, areas=>array('name'=>name, 'uid'=>uid))
```

I just need to know how to do an insertAfter on the **a** tag within the **li** object.

Comment: var li = tree.append('<li class="zone"><a href="#">'+j[i].name+'</a></li>');  Here, li = tree  BTW, closest() is looking for ancestors, is your <a> ancestor of li?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create an html string and append that to your `tree` object:

```
var html = '<li class="zone"><a href="#">'+j[i].name+'</a>';
$.each(j[i].areas, function(i, item) {
    html += '<li class="area" data-area-uid="'+item.uid+'">'+item.name+'</li>';
});
html += '</li>'; //close first li element

tree.append(html);
```

As an aside, your issue has to due with your usage of `closest`, which looks for the closest **parent** that matches the selector. You would want to use `children` which just searches through the direct children of the element.

Answer (score 1):

You could look for the anchor inside and then use `.after()`:

```
li.children('a').after(areas);
```

Although, in this case you could also just use `.append()`:

```
li.append(areas); // this will go behind <a>
```